# How to uncheck checkbox when append row using jquery in which checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

But when I append row  using jquery in which chechbox automatically comes checked how to unchecked checkbox

my code to append row is

var num = $('#operationtbl > tbody > tr').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have

```
var newNum = new Number(num + 1);

var row = $('#operationtbl > tbody > tr:last').clone(true);

$("td input:text", row).val("");
$("td input:hidden", row).val("");
$("td select", row).val("");
$('td checkbox', row).attr('checked', false);

$("td input:hidden[name^=hiddoprid]", row).attr('id', 'hiddoprid' + newNum);
$("td input:text[name^=oprnumber]", row).attr('id', 'oprnumber' + newNum);
$("td select[name^=oprname]", row).attr('id', 'oprname' + newNum);
$("td select[name^=oprdept]", row).attr('id', 'oprdept' + newNum);
$("td input:text[name^=oprleadtime]", row).attr('id', 'oprleadtime' + newNum);
$("td input:text[name^=startqty]", row).attr('id', 'startqty' + newNum);
$("td input:text[name^=completeqty]", row).attr('id', 'completeqty' + newNum);
$("td input:text[name^=openqty]", row).attr('id', 'openqty' + newNum);
$("td select[name^=inspectionplan]", row).attr('id', 'inspectionplan' + newNum);
$("td input:text[name^=oprstartdate]", row).attr('id', 'oprstartdate' + newNum);
$("td input:text[name^=oprenddate]", row).attr('id', 'oprenddate' + newNum);

$("img[id^=deleteoperatinbtn]", row).attr('id', "deleteoperatinbtn" + newNum);

$(".hiddseloprid", row).html('');

$("[name='oprstartdate[]']").unwrap("<div class='jdpicker_w'></div>");//Add jdpicker calendar
$("[name='oprstartdate[]']").siblings().remove();//Add jdpicker calendar

$("[name='oprenddate[]']").unwrap("<div class='jdpicker_w'></div>");//Add jdpicker calendar
$("[name='oprenddate[]']").siblings().remove();//Add jdpicker calendar

$("#operationtbl").append(row);
```

Comment: what you have try so far? Please also share your code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `attr()`, you can use `.prop()`. Replace below line

```
$('td checkbox', row).attr('checked', false);
```

to

```
$('td checkbox', row).prop('checked', false);
```

**[.prop() API Document](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**

Comment: can you share a jsifiddle link?

Comment: why not possible? You can recreate the problem using not exact but similar code

Comment: my code is properly working only problem is that if checkbox of last row is checked then by clicking on add button another row with textbox and checkbox is add but the checkbox already come checked and if last row checkbox is unchecked then there is no issue it will add row with unchecked checkbox

Comment: then how will i help you?